# I don't have a sidebar

Tags: dual-boot

I have included an image description of the power-up screen here [Screen when system powered up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR1z6.jpg) [Information about my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIYl6.jpg)and info about my system. I have a UBUNTU 20.04.6 LTS Desktop with a dual boot to Windows 11.
^^^^ 12-01-2023  ^^^^^
I am a new user of Ubuntu. I have a dual boot environment with Windows 11. When I boot into Ubuntu, I have no programs or windows. There is nothing that I have the knowledge to do.

Comment: Show us what you are seeing: Take a clear, readable photo of your screen. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1494506/edit) above to provide a link to the photo.

Comment: check gnome settings app